# About an ambiguity that really prevents me from understanding the principle " the laws of physics are invariant in all inertial frames"

Tags: classical-mechanics, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

The principle is often stated as self explanatory ....

The sentence " the laws of physics are the same in all inertial frames" could mean 2 very different things ( at least from my point of view).

(1) Does it mean that there is a special class of frames that are "inertial" ( and some that are not) , and that, in this special class, the laws of physics are invariant?

(2) Or should the property " being inertial"  ( in translation one relatively to the other) " be seen as an equivalence relation that partitions the set of frames, in such a way  that, in each " cell" of this partition, there are invariant laws of physics ( though these invariant laws are not the same for all the classes of frames).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct interpretation is (1). The principle states that, when writing the laws of physics using coordinates (spatial and temporal) of  reference  frames, the form of the laws turn out to be  *identical* in every *inertial* reference frame.
*Invariant* is used here as *of identical form*.

Comment: It is worth noting that there is also an ambiguity about what "the laws of nature" means. Often this is taken to refer to the Lagrangian which is the mathematical structure that dictates the dynamics. More strictly, it refers to the equations of motion (the actual dynamics) alone in classical physics, or to observation probabilities in quantum physics. Although the strict sense makes more philosophical sense, the technical requirement is usually for the broader Lagrangian sense since it's easier to apply (and automatically leads to the stricter sense).

Comment: Yes there is that ambiguity... And that ambiguity was fundamental in, for instance, passing from classical physics to relativistic physics.

Comment: Sometimes that invariance is identified with the notion of covariance (the laws have to be written in terms of tensors). However this point if view is reductive and misleading since there are cases where the laws are identical in form but are not covariant. This is the case of the Hamiltonian formulation of classical mechanics.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what distinction you are making, but the answer is that your paragraph labelled (1) is correct.

You must bear in mind that reference frames are fictitious abstractions that we overlay on reality to allow us to keep track of distances and elapsed times. Reality remains the same regardless of which frame we superimpose. The question is whether we can use the same mathematical formulae to calculate effects regardless of which frame we overlay. Clearly that is not always true- if you pick two frames, one of which is rotating, moving east and yo-yoing up and down relative to the other, you will need to make some adjustments if you switch from one to the other, as you would if you used a frame with a logarithmic scale, for example.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It seems like an answer to me.

Comment: The distinction being made is if the physics in a rotating frame, and the physics in a rotating frame _that's also moving to the right_ are the same. Neither is inertial, but does relativity have something to say on the matter?

Answer (score 3):

Take a lift from the first floor to the tenth floor. You feel getting heavier when the lift leaves the first floor and getting lighter when it arrives at the tenth floor.

You can explain this by noticing that the lift is not an inertial frame. It's accelerated and later slowed down, relative to earth (which is not strictly speaking an inertial frame, but much more so than the lift).

If you claimed that the lift was an inertial frame, you would have to come up with some really, really strange laws of physics that come into effect at the start and end of any trip in the lift and explain the change in weight.

Comment: For all practical purposes, a lift can usually be considered an inertial frame during the major portion of its travel excluding the starting and ending acceleration.  An "ideal" lift does not accelerate during most of its travel.  Trains are also often used in thought experiments as an inertial frame, but technically a real train has acceleration periods also.  So pedagogically speaking, such conditions should be stated and not left as unstated assumptions.

Comment: In relativity the lift is not inertial, because the cable causes an acceleration upwards at $g$, to avoid freefall. In Newtonian conceptual understanding, gravity is called a force, hence the sum of the cable force and gravity is approximately zero